# Multiple FILE pointers and fgets

Tags: c, linux

Say you have two `FILE` pointers (`stdin` and `popen`) that are being written to in real-time.

If you interleave `fgets` calls, then you might block on one that is not receiving data, while the other has data arriving that you are not processing.

How is this solved idiomatically? Is multi-threading necessary? Is there anyway to block until at least one `FILE` has available input?

Comment: Multi-threading along with a synchronized queue can certainly help, but make sure you don't open too many files together.

Comment: Theoretically, you can use non-blocking reads, but it looks hazardous to me so never tried it. Better to have sequential blocking commands on separate threads with sufficient buffering to minimise the overhead of creating the thread, where possible.

Comment: You might be able to use `fileno()` to get the underlying file descriptors, then use `poll()` or `select()` on those. I don't know how brittle that would be though.